# Find the projection of the curve of intersection between two solids $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=\frac{1}{2}y$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find the curve of intersection and its projection of the $xy$-plane of the solids $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=\dfrac{1}{2}y$. Following my calculations it's given by the parametric equation:

> $$\varphi(t)=(\frac{1}{4}\cos t,\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\sin t,\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\sin t)$$

where $0\le t\le 2\pi$.

If we disregard the $z$ part we get the projection on the $xy$-plane:

$$\alpha(t)=(\frac{1}{4}\cos t,\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\sin t)$$

I would like to know if I'm right.

Answer (score 1):

(+1) Right and you applied a good simple approach. Maybe someone interests more details.

Further details shows the curve of intersection $z=x^2+y^2$ and the plane $z=\dfrac{1}{2}y$ 
is an ellipse and we find it's apogee and perigee with $x=0$ in
$$\varphi(t)=\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos t,\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\sin t,\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\sin t\right)$$
which gives us $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,\dfrac12,\dfrac14)$ so $2a=\sqrt{(\dfrac12)^2+(\dfrac14)^2}$ or $\color{blue}{a=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}$. The center of ellipse is $(0,\dfrac14,\dfrac18)$, 
and contact between the line $8z=4y=1$ and $z=x^2+y^2$ are $(\pm\dfrac14,\dfrac14,\dfrac18)$ that shows $\color{blue}{b=\dfrac14}$ and then $c^2=a^2-b^2=\dfrac{1}{64}$ hence $\color{blue}{e=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{5}}$.

The projection of this ellipse on $xy$-plane, as you said is the planar curve 
$$\alpha(t)=\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos t,\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\sin t\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

[I've plot them](https://www.geogebra.org/o/eHmrVQy6). Not reputed as a rigorous way to check results, but to my understanding, it amounts almost the same as checking the equations for the curves into the equations for the surfaces.